# How can I rotate the map?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I just started playing Realm of the Mad God on Steam. The intro video shows the map rotating as players move around it, but I can't find any key (or key maps) which do this.

Is it possible to do in the Steam version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the options. There's an option to set the map's default angle to 45 degrees (default) or 0 degrees as well as some options to change hotkeys and there's where you'll find the defaults for rotating the map (which I don't know off the top of my head but I believe they're Q and E). You have to unlock the map for rotation in the options though before you can use Q and E, this is of course assuming that those are the right keys to do it with.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't found the options panel. (It's where the "Nexus" button is when you're inside the Nexus.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Having the minimap at a different angle than the ingame map was quite annoying.